# Minimizing vector problem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Show that the subset $ M = ${$y= (\eta_j) ;  \sum \eta _j= 1$} of complex space $\mathbb{C^{n}}$  is complete and convex. Find the vector of minimum norm in M.

It makes sense to prove this since that M is not a subspace??
If $x=(1,0,...,0)  \space y=(0,1,...,0)$ then $x+y=(1,1,0,..,0) \notin M$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, $M$ is not a subspace. But it can still be a convex set. Every subspace is convex, but not vice versa.

Comment: But I can't conclude that it's complete then because it's not subspace? That's my main question.

Comment: @TiagoPerdigão The same is true of completeness, a subset of a metric space can be complete.